Trying to fetch the chromium source code using `fetch chromium` gives error
I am trying to fetch the chromium source code but I am encountering some error and unable to find the cause.
This is the output on running fetch --no-history chromium:
C:\chromium>fetch --no-history chromium
Updating depot_tools...
Downloading CIPD client for windows-amd64 from https://chrome-infra-packages.appspot.com/client?platform=windows-amd64&version=git_revision:b1f414539ac10cc67a0250890a38712cc06cf102...
Running: 'C:\Users\jayka\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\python_venv-4uhfsjhi5for37hmdjer3ht0k0\contents\Scripts\python3.exe' 'C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py' root
WARNING: Your metrics.cfg file was invalid or nonexistent. A new one will be created.
Running: 'C:\Users\jayka\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\python_venv-4uhfsjhi5for37hmdjer3ht0k0\contents\Scripts\python3.exe' 'C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py' config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "name": "src",
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git",
    "managed": False,
    "custom_deps": {},
    "custom_vars": {},
  },
]
'
Running: 'C:\Users\jayka\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\python_venv-4uhfsjhi5for37hmdjer3ht0k0\contents\Scripts\python3.exe' 'C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py' sync --no-history
Syncing projects: 100% ( 1/ 1) src
src (ERROR)
----------------------------------------
[0:00:00] Started.
[0:01:15]
[0:01:20] _____ Conflicting directory found in C:\chromium\src. Moving to C:\chromium\_bad_scm\src9c3a8srx.
----------------------------------------


Warnings:
Conflicting directory C:\chromium\src moved to C:\chromium\_bad_scm\src9c3a8srx.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 832, in update
    self.current_revision = self._Clone(revision, url, options)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 1372, in _Clone
    git_auth.ConfigureGlobal('/', url)
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\git_auth.py", line 301, in ConfigureGlobal
    ConfigChanger.new_for_remote(cwd, remote_url).apply_global(cwd)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\git_auth.py", line 122, in new_for_remote
    c.mode = cls._infer_mode(cwd, c._shortname + '-review.googlesource.com')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\git_auth.py", line 133, in _infer_mode
    if not gerrit_util.GitCredsAuthenticator.gerrit_account_exists(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gerrit_util.py", line 913, in gerrit_account_exists
    scm.GIT.SetConfig(cwd, 'depot-tools.hostHasAccount', host, append=True)
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\scm.py", line 834, in SetConfig
    GIT._get_config_state(cwd).SetConfig(key,
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\scm.py", line 369, in SetConfig
    self._impl.set_config(key, value, append=append, scope=scope)
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\scm.py", line 434, in set_config
    GIT.Capture(args, cwd=self.root)
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\scm.py", line 710, in Capture
    return git_common.run(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\git_common.py", line 865, in run
    return run_with_stderr(*cmd, **kwargs)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\git_common.py", line 944, in run_with_stderr
    raise ex
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\git_common.py", line 934, in run_with_stderr
    return _run_with_stderr(*cmd, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\git_common.py", line 971, in _run_with_stderr
    raise subprocess2.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, os.getcwd(), stdout,
subprocess2.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe -c color.ui=never config --local depot-tools.hostHasAccount chromium-review.googlesource.com --add' returned non-zero exit status 128 in C:\chromium
fatal: --local can only be used inside a git repository


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jayka\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\cpython+77vkdc5f3t4dm3hikhtc9e5djk\contents\bin\Lib\shutil.py", line 853, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\chromium\\src' -> 'C:\\chromium\\_bad_scm\\src9c3a8srx\\src'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\metrics.py", line 302, in print_notice_and_exit
    yield
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 4660, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 4646, in main
    return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\subcommand.py", line 254, in execute
    return command(parser, args[1:])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 3999, in CMDsync
    ret = client.RunOnDeps('update', args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 2439, in RunOnDeps
    work_queue.flush(revision_overrides,
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 1028, in flush
    reraise(e[0], e[1], e[2])
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 53, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 1107, in run
    self.item.run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 1251, in run
    self._got_revision = self._used_scm.RunCommand(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 137, in RunCommand
    return getattr(self, command)(options, args, file_list)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 664, in wrapper
    return_val = f(*args)
                 ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 835, in update
    self._DeleteOrMove(options.force)
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 209, in _DeleteOrMove
    shutil.move(self.checkout_path, dest_path)
  File "C:\Users\jayka\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\cpython+77vkdc5f3t4dm3hikhtc9e5djk\contents\bin\Lib\shutil.py", line 873, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\jayka\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\cpython+77vkdc5f3t4dm3hikhtc9e5djk\contents\bin\Lib\shutil.py", line 448, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\jayka\AppData\Local\.vpython-root\store\cpython+77vkdc5f3t4dm3hikhtc9e5djk\contents\bin\Lib\shutil.py", line 256, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\chromium\\src'

Subprocess failed with return code 1.


I have successfully downloaded the code before using the documentation, but getting error this time
I have rechecked the environment variables, version of python3, version of depot tools, version of git.
I have tried deleting the whole "chromium" folder before running the fetch chromium/fetch --no-history chromium in it.
I have also tried making a new folder with different name (e.g. chromium_new) before running the fetch chromium command.
I have tried both fetch chromium and fetch --no-history chromium.

Also, here it is suggested not to use git clone.Is it a problem if I use it instead.

did you try changing the directory name to something else and try fetch chromium again?
